# Combinations of sandwiches

Tags: combinatorics

My stats summer packet proposes the question: "if a sandwich shop has $3$ different types of meat, $4$ different types of bread, and $3$ different types of cheese. How many types of sandwiches can you create if you must have meat, bread, and cheese on each?"

My gut instinct is to do $3!*4!*3!$, but I'm not sure. However, while I type this, I wonder if it makes more sense to simply do $3*4*3$, since for each $3$ types of meat, one can choose one of $4$ breads, and then one of $3$ cheeses.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is $3\cdot 4\cdot 3$.  You have  explained why towards the end.

Comment: Assuming you only use one type of bread, meat and cheese each, and it does not matter in which order you use them (say, you will always put bread-meat-cheese, and bread-cheese-meat is obviously not much different, albeit a bit weird), then your second thought is correct.

Comment: Make it a custom to type your questions. Apparantly that can open up your mind.

Comment: Usually on sandwiches bread, cheese and meat go in specific order. This changes the solution if it is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second impression was "right"; the answer is $36$ in one restricted interpretation of the problem, in which a sandwich has precisely one type of bread, one type of meat, and one type of cheese.

The largest possible interpretation is that a sandwich consists of a top bread, 1 to 3 types of meat, 1 to 3 types of cheese, and a bottom bread which could be different from the top slice of bread (but two sandwiches are considered the same if the only difference is turning one upside down).  The answer to that problem involves, for example, seven possible combination of meats, and is
$$
\binom{4}{2}_\mbox{bread}\cdot (2^3-1)_\mbox{meat}\cdot (2^3-1)_\mbox{cheese}=6\cdot 7 \cdot 7 = 594
$$
If you must use the same type of bread top and bottom the answer is 
$$
\binom{4}{1}_\mbox{bread}\cdot (2^3-1)_\mbox{meat}\cdot (2^3-1)_\mbox{cheese}=4\cdot 7 \cdot 7 = 396
$$

Comment: Thanks! Given that it is an introductory packet, I'll assume one of each.

Comment: In the first version it would probably be $10$ bread. The multiplications look off.